# dm_exec_query_stats returns worker time greater than elapsed time

Tags: sql-server, performance-monitoring, database-performance

I frequently query sys.dm_exec_query_stats to find expensive queries.  I've noticed that in some cases the total_worker_time is greater than the total_elapsed_time.  Does anyone know why this would be the case?  I'm looking at an example right now where the last_worker_time is greater than the last_elapsed_time.

Perhaps the worker time is the sum across multiple processors/cores?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed the sum of multiple processors' work.  I'd bet dollars to donuts that if you look at the cached plan that you'll see some parallelism in it.

Comment: Yup, I did notice the parallelism included in the query plan. Thanks for confirming - I couldn't find any documentation regarding this.